# Python: Extract chapter from long txt (or delete all other chapters)

Tags: python, text

My problem is:
I have several long txt files with many chapters of which I want to extract one. The text within these chapters differs between files.

Identification should be done using the title of the chapter and the title of the next chapter, which are the same for all files. These identification-titles are in the file more than once, but I want to only use their first occurrence...

Thus the logic is something like:

delete text; identification title (first occurrence) "start"; keep title and text; identification title (first occurrence) "end"; delete text

The goal is a program, which will automatically open all files and edit them in the stated way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: I can: open the files with a for-loop in r+ mode and seek my identification title. I do not know: how to only refer to the first identification-title (maybe with a counter - don't know how exactly though as the counter will be say 5 in the end); how to truncate everything before the identification title "start".... Sorry for not being specific enough in my first request!

Answer (score 0):

I found a (somehow long) answer, which does only delete the first part of the text (that means the chapter is not extracted but at least it is at the top, which is sufficient for me)... maybe someone'll have the same problem:

```
import os  
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if file == "delete_first_part.py":
        pass
    elif os.path.isfile(file):
        # open the file, delete all lines before "word to begin", write rest to file
        f = open(file,"r+")
        lines = reversed(f.readlines())

        f.seek(0)
        strings = ("Word to Begin")
        for line in lines:
            if any(s in line for s in strings):
                f.write(line)
                f.truncate()
                print file
                break
            else:
                f.write(line)

        f.close()

        f = open(file,"r+")
        lines = reversed(f.readlines())

        f.seek(0)

        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)

        f.close()
```

I read the file from the end, search for my "word to begin", truncate the rest of the text and break the loop. Then write to file, open it again and read from the end -> the end up with the text in the "right" direction.